# Canvas clipping region and the canvas stack

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have started working through the O'Reilly book "HTML5 Canvas." I'm in the second chapter, and one of the examples presents code which is not very well explained. Example 2-5:

1. draw a black box
2. push state
3. set small clipping region in top left
4. draw circle
5. pop state
6. set large clipping region
7. draw another circle

But I'm having trouble understanding some things:

```
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 200);

context.save();

context.beginPath();
context.rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
context.clip();

context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = 'red';
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();

context.restore();

context.beginPath();
context.rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
context.clip();

context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

My questions:

First, does context.clip() implicitly close the context path ("context.closePath()")? It is preceded by a context.beginPath(), and followed by another context.beginPath(). Like this:

```
context.beginPath();
context.rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
context.clip();
context.beginPath();
```

Second, why is it necessary to push the context state? Why can't I just change the clipping region? It seems to be necessary, because it doesn't work without pushing the state. If I don't push the state and then restore it, the big blue circle does not show up, and I don't understand why.

Comment: beginPath begins a whole new path and dumps the old path. closePath is not related to beginPath. ClosePath simply create a lineTo from the current position to the last moveTo position You can have as many closePaths as you like, You can only have one beginPath per rendering output (stroke(), fill() ) . Clips are cumulative, each time you add a clip it is clipped by the previous clip, each clip area becomes smaller and smaller. To revert you must use save and restore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Does context.clip() implicitly close the context path ?...
>
>   It is preceded by a context.beginPath(), and followed by another context.beginPath(). Like this: [...]*

Yes, this is only way to create a close shape which is required for clipping so if a closePath() isn't called clip() will close the path internally.

The [specification states:](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-clip)

> Open subpaths must be implicitly closed when computing the clipping region, without affecting the actual subpaths.

`beginPath()` will clear the current main path and all its sub-paths. The clipping still resides active though, but now you can do other path operations which will be affected by the clip region when rasterized.

> *Why is it necessary to push the context state?*

There is no way to reset a clip region although it has been suggested and discussed (there is a [resetClip()](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-resetclip) in the standard but not yet widely supported). [Calling `clip()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-clip) several times -

> The clip() method must create a new clipping region by calculating the intersection of the current clipping region [...]

In other words, it won't be replaced if we say defined a clip region for the entire draw surface.

So the only way we can remove a clip is to save the state, set clip then restore to remove it.

Comment: Good explanations! Just a small add-on for those edge cases where it applies: Clipping is also cleared when resizing the canvas element. This is because all context state is reset when resizing the canvas element.